# How to access district by district name in antv using React js?

Tags: reactjs, maps, antv

I want to create a map for showing the number of products selling in a particular district of India. in the backend, I have data like "West Delhi" name of the district and total count.I want to display the data in ant vision L7 district map. But not able to understand How they are consuming the data.

Comment: What issue that you don't understand? Like, you don't know how to fetch data from back-end?

Comment: I know how to fetch data from backend but the issue is for creating map I am getting district name like "kolkata" so by this name i want to access kolkata area in map.

Comment: I think what you want is Google Maps. Try to google "using Google Map with React". There are some library that even help you with this

Comment: I Have tried for google map but not getting for district

Comment: I just [try with Google](https://www.google.com/maps/place/West+Delhi,+Delhi,+India/@28.6540779,76.9272746,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x390d045709693ca7:0x439edb221545a927!8m2!3d28.6663433!4d77.067959) and it works?

Comment: can you please share the procedure. how you tries?